# Having trouble adding graphics to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, java-2d

I have looked online, but I am still having trouble understanding how to add graphics to a JPanel

Here is the code for my panel class:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public GamePanel(){

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("asd", 5, 5);
    }

}
```

And my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //i is an instance of GamePanel
    frame.add(i);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Text will only appear in a very tiny section of the screen (this applies to any graphics object I try to draw). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FlowLayout` respects preferred sizes of components. Therefore override `getPreferredSize` to give your `JPanel` a visible size rather than the default zero size Dimension that the panel currently has after `JFrame#pack` is called:

```
class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // added to paint child components
        g.drawString("asd", 5, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 300);
    }
}
```

*Edit:*

To eliminate gap between `JPanel` and its containing `JFrame`, set the vertical gap to `0`:

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just one more question, when I try drawing a rectangle at 0, 0, while the rectangle properly starts at an x coordinate of 0, the y coordinate seems to be a tiny bit higher than 0 (there is a bit of a gap between the top of the screen and the rectangle). Is this normal? If so, can I fix this? EDIT: My panel and frame sizes are the same and everything

Comment: This is a default gap used by `FlowLayout`. Use zero size vertical gap to correct this. See update

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump out

1. Your Game panel has no preferred size, which, by default, makes 0x0. `FlowLayout` will use this information to make decisions about how best to layout your panel. Because the size is 0x0, the repaint manager will ignore it. Try overriding the `getPreferredSize` method and return a appropriate size or use a layout manager that does not use the preferred size, like `BorderLayout`
2. Your `paintComponent` method MUST call `super.paintComponet`